# Prevent line break in interpolated string

Tags: dart, string-interpolation

I having long string with interpolation in code. I am writing it as:

```
"""
$a: aaaaa
$b: bbbbb
$c: ccccc
"""
```

I do not want to write it in one line because readability. But in `Text` widget it displays also in column:
[image]

How to prevent line breaking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a multi-line string literal, then you will get newlines in the string.
You can remove them by doing:

```dart
var string = """
$a: aaaaa
$b: bbbbb
$c: ccccc
""".removeAll("\n");
```

That should leave you without any newlines.

Alternatively you can use multiple adjacent string literals instead:

```dart
var string =
  "$a: aaaa"
  "$b: bbbb"
  "$c: cccc";
```

Adjacent string literals are combined into a single string value, and there are no extra newlines (if you want them, you have to add `\n` yourself). You also don't have to worry about leading whitespace on the lines.